# How can show arabic numbers in label

Tags: objective-c, numbers, label, arabic

How can show arabic numbers in label?
better is i say how can i convert en numbers to arabic numbers.
like ۱و۲و۳و...
iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to "pipe" the arabic numbers to google translate, then retrieve the output.  [Google Translate api](http://code.google.com/apis/language/)

If the only numbers you wish to translate are (1, 2, 3, 4) then you can use find-and-replace

Answer (score 0):

add arabic or farsi language to your mac keyboard language and just change the language on your computer then type the numbers and you'll see arabic numbers